# Is there a useable error metric for rubics cube non-linear solver?

Tags: metric-spaces, nonlinear-optimization, rubiks-cube

There exist step-by-step algorithms for solving rubics cubes. However, in the midst of an ongoing solution, often the state of the rubics cube can become more convoluted before the increased regularization can become apparent.

Thus the step-wise rubics solving algorithm is non-linear. Is there an algebraic error metric that measures how far a rubics cube is from being solved?

Comment: rubics $\to$ Rubik's

Comment: Have you seen [this site](https://www.speedsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Metric) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie thank you. I am absolutely terrible at Rubik's cubes, but luckily my concern is about non-linear optimizations in general. :) How do we know we are "getting closer" to a solution (for example zeros in systems of simultaneous non-linear equations) when iterating using a numerical algorithm?

Comment: What properties does your metric need to have? There is no known metric that is perfect, cause if there was then you could just solve it optimally by hill-climbing with that metric. It takes quite a bit of effort to compute an optimal solution of a scrambled cube. About two-thirds of all cube positions [take 18 moves](http://cube20.org/) to solve optimally, and none take more than 20 moves. Unfortunately, the only way we know so far to distinguish between a position that takes say 17 moves and one that takes 18 is to actually search and find optimal solutions.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis thank you. I find it interesting how the Rubik's cube algorithm was first discovered, because the non-linearity seems to make it hard to use systematic optimizations to find the correct algorithm for the first time. Was it somebody's "hunch" that first solved the Rubik's cube, or was it exhaustive combinatorial search of the solution steps?

Comment: The original solving methods did not come from a hunch, trial and error, or exhaustive search. There are logical (mathematical) techniques for discovering useful move sequences and for generalising them. You can read about them [in this Puzzling SE post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/54060/20814). Of course, nowadays many short move sequences that are used by fast solvers were found with computer searches.